# switching form in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

i have a some code in JSP:

```
<c:if test="${user != null}">
<form action="update" method="post">
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${user == null}">
    <form action="insert" method="post">
        </c:if>
```

how to convert it to Thymeleaf?

i need switching action of form while condition IF of Thymeleaf is true:

```
<form th:if=condition 1 is true action="insert" method="post"
th:if=condition 2 is true action="add" method="post"
>

-- some code of form

</form>
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions) will help you to achieve the requirements. The JSP logic will be much simpler (literally one line) with Thymeleaf and looks similar to ...

```
<form th:action="${user != null}? 'update' : 'insert'" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div th:with="methodName=${user ==null ? 'insert' : 'update'}">
<form th:action="${methodName}" method="post">
```